# post request with retrofit gets responce a s bad request in android

Tags: android, post, http-headers, retrofit

I am using https://docs.ngenius-payments.com/reference#hosted-payment-page for payment in android

Headers:
Add these headers to your request (note that you should replace 'your_api_key' with the service account API key in the Getting started section).

Header  Value
Content-Type   application/vnd.ni-identity.v1+json

Authorization  Basic: your_api_key

Body / Form Data:
Add the following information to the form/body content of your request.

Example request (body):
JSON
{
    ‘realmName’: ‘ni’
}

these are the headers and content type and i created a post method using retrofit

```
   public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient() {
    //If condition to ensure we don't create multiple retrofit instances in a single application
    if (retrofit == null) {
        //Defining the Retrofit using Builder
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL) //This is the only mandatory call on Builder object.
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) // Convertor library used to convert response into POJO
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;

}
```

My api interface is

```
@POST("identity/auth/access-token")
Call<NgeniusPaymentAccessTokenModel> nGeniusAccessToken(@Header("content-type") String ContentType, @Header("authorization") String apiKey, @Body JsonObject object);
```

and i call it by

```
    JsonObject postParam = new JsonObject();
        try {
            postParam.addProperty("realmName", "ni");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 Call call = apiService.nGeniusAccessToken(contentType, "Basic "+apiKey, postParam);
```

i am getting the responce as error telling its a bad request, how to solve this

Comment: You are sending a bad request body which is not in the expected format for your backend. Please clear out the request body requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one worked for me i put all of the headers in a header map

creata a map

```
Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        stringMap.put("Authorization", "auth");
        stringMap.put("Content-Type", "CONTENT_TYPE");
        stringMap.put("accept", "accept");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

api interface looks like

```
@POST("transactions/orders")
Call<ResponseBody> nCreateOrder(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,String out, @Body JsonObject object);
```

now call it by

```
 nCreateOrder(stringMap ,"out",jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
String contentType = "application/vnd.ni-identity.v1+json";
String authorization = "Basic: "+apiKey;
JSONObject postParam = new JSONObject();
        try {
            postParam.put("realmName", "ni");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 Call call = apiService.nGeniusAccessToken(contentType, authorization, postParam);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" Can you explain @jin